# Pi4J v2 SPI w/ GPIO Pin

Tags: raspberry-pi, pi4j

I'm trying to use Pi4J to talk to an SPI device where the CS pin is a GPIO pin (GPIO 5) and not one of the mapped CS pins.  I don't see how to configure it this way in any of the examples or javadocs.  I think it would be somewhere on my SpiConfig line.

```
        // Initialize Pi4J with an auto context
        // An auto context includes AUTO-DETECT BINDINGS enabled
        // which will load all detected Pi4J extension libraries
        // (Platforms and Providers) in the class path
        var pi4j = Pi4J.newAutoContext();

        // create SPI config
        SpiConfig config = Spi.newConfigBuilder(pi4j).id("thermocouple-1")
                        .name("Thermocouple 1").bus(SpiBus.BUS_1)
                        .chipSelect(SpiChipSelect.CS_0).build();

        // get a SPI I/O provider from the Pi4J context
        SpiProvider spiProvider = pi4j.provider("pigpio-spi");

        // use try-with-resources to auto-close SPI when complete
        try (Spi spi = spiProvider.create(config)) {
                byte data[] = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
```

It looks like this is possible with v1 of the library, but it's not the same in v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up posting on the pi4j project on GitHub and through those conversations worked out what I needed.  Here is a cross post from [there](https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j-v2/discussions/264).

> Well looking at the DAC8552 example was the key. Here is a working
> version that asks the device for it's ID (register 0xD0) and gives the
> correct answer for BME280 (0x60). Thanks for the assist. Here is the
> working code (needs to be cleaned up, but it's a basic start).

```
package com.pi4j.example.spi;

import com.pi4j.Pi4J;
import com.pi4j.context.Context;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.digital.DigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.digital.DigitalState;
import com.pi4j.io.spi.Spi;
import com.pi4j.io.spi.SpiBus;
import com.pi4j.io.spi.SpiChipSelect;
import com.pi4j.io.spi.SpiMode;
import com.pi4j.util.Console;
import com.pi4j.util.StringUtil;

public class BmeTest {

    private static final SpiBus spiBus = SpiBus.BUS_0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final var console = new Console();

        // print program title/header
        console.title("<-- The Pi4J Project -->",
                "Basic SPI Communications Example");

        Context pi4j = Pi4J.newAutoContext();
        var spiConfig = Spi.newConfigBuilder(pi4j)
                .id("SPI" + spiBus + "_BME280")
                .name("BME280")
                .bus(spiBus)
                .chipSelect(SpiChipSelect.CS_0) // not used
                .mode(SpiMode.MODE_0)
                .provider("pigpio-spi")
                .build();

        // required all configs
        var outputConfig = DigitalOutput.newConfigBuilder(pi4j)
                .id("CS_GPIO5")
                .name("CS GPIO5")
                .address(5)
                .shutdown(DigitalState.HIGH)
                .initial(DigitalState.HIGH)
                .provider("pigpio-digital-output");

        DigitalOutput csGpio = null;
        try {
            csGpio = pi4j.create(outputConfig);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            console.println("create DigOut DRDY failed");
            System.exit(202);
        }

        // use try-with-resources to auto-close SPI when complete
        try (var spi = pi4j.create(spiConfig)) {
            byte data[] = new byte[] { (byte) (0x80 | 0xD0), (byte) 0x00 };

            csGpio.high();
            csGpio.low();
            spi.transfer(data, data);
            csGpio.high();

            // take a breath to allow time for the SPI
            // data to get updated in the SPI device
            Thread.sleep(100);

            // read data back from the SPI channel
            console.println("--------------------------------------");
            console.println("SPI [READ] :");
            console.println("  [BYTES]  0x" + StringUtil.toHexString(data));
            console.println("  [STRING] " + new String(data));
            console.println("--------------------------------------");
        }

        // shutdown Pi4J
        console.println("ATTEMPTING TO SHUTDOWN/TERMINATE THIS PROGRAM");
        pi4j.shutdown();
    }
}
```

With the following output:

```
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console - ************************************************************
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console - ************************************************************
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console -
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console - <-- The Pi4J Project -->
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console - Basic SPI Communications Example
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console -
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console - ************************************************************
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console - ************************************************************
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console -
[main] INFO com.pi4j.Pi4J - New auto context
[main] INFO com.pi4j.Pi4J - New context builder
[main] INFO com.pi4j.platform.impl.DefaultRuntimePlatforms - adding platform to managed platform map [id=raspberrypi; name=RaspberryPi Platform; priority=5; class=com.pi4j.plugin.raspberrypi.platform.RaspberryPiPlatform]
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console - --------------------------------------
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console - SPI [READ] :
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console - [BYTES] 0xFF 60
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console - [STRING] �`
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console - --------------------------------------
[main] INFO com.pi4j.util.Console - ATTEMPTING TO SHUTDOWN/TERMINATE THIS PROGRAM
```